# How is the click target providing the clicked button in my event listener?

Tags: javascript

Here I am going through an array of buttons and on each one I create an EventListener. In these EventListeners I'm creating an anonymous fonction that takes a parameter evt.

I don't understand how JavaScript allows me to use `x.target` to refer to the button being clicked.

```
export function ajoutListenersAvis() {
  const piecesElements = document.querySelectorAll(".fiches article button");
  for (let i = 0; i < piecesElements.length; i++) {
    piecesElements[i].addEventListener("click", function(x) {
      const id = x.target.dataset.id;
      fetch(`http://localhost:8081/pieces/${id}/avis`);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The browser passes an event object (`x`) in to your event handler function when the "click" occurs.

Comment: The browser creates an Event object that contains information about the event that was triggered. It fills in the `target` property with the DOM element associated with the event -- in the case of a `click` event, it's the element you clicked on.

Comment: How comes (x) is an event object ?

Comment: Because it's the argument to the listener. The browser automatically passes the event as the argument.

Comment: you can type `(e)`, or `(event)` and it won't matter, that is just how you choose to call it

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your code, `x` is actually an event object that represents the event being fired when a button is clicked. In this case, it is the `click` event.

When you define an event listener with `addEventListener`, the function you pass as the second argument is automatically passed an event object as its first parameter. This is why you are able to reference `x` in your anonymous function.

`x.target` in your code refers to the button element that was clicked, because `target` is a property of the event object that points to the DOM element on which the event was triggered. Since you are attaching the event listener to a button element, `x.target` will always refer to the button element that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Although people have answered it in a technical manner, here is a visual representation in a most basic format.

You can refer to the arguments passed to a function however you would like. It doesn't change the content in the argument, just how you refer to it.

```js
const taco = "Pizza";

function test(cheese){
  console.log(cheese)
}

test(taco)
```